# How could i solve the problem for Javascript Fetch

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch-api

Below committed code is axios. Which is working fine, but JavaScript fetch is not working. Let me know what is the issue in the code. How to fix it. Please explain it in a simple way.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function Datafetching() {
    const [posts, setposts] = useState([])

    const getMovieRequest = async () => {
        const url = `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`;
        
  
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const responseJson = await response.json()
     
        if (responseJson.data){
            setposts(responseJson.data)
            console.log(responseJson.data)
                }
        
           }

    useEffect(() => {
        // axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        // .then(res => {
        //     console.log(res)
        //     setposts(res.data)
        // })
        // .catch(err => {
        //     console.log(err)
        // })

        getMovieRequest()        
    })



    return (
        <div>
            <ul>{
                posts.map(post => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>)
                }
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Datafetching
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? You call `getMovieRequest` and then... do nothing with the results.

Comment: Have you checked for any errors in the console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`responseData` contains the data as array, not `responseData.data`:

```
if (responseJson){
     setposts(responseJson)
     console.log(responseJson)
}
```